# Cordova Build windows 10

Tags: cordova, windows-10

I am building a Ionic/Cordova app for windows 10. Dev machine is Windows 10.

The app does not works Completely i.e certain features does not work 
- However if I goto debug console(F12) and change theBrowser Profile  Mode to "Windows 10 Mobile" everything works perfectly.

How can I make the same programmatically i.e set mode to windows 10.

I have tried setting preferences in config.xml

Thanks in advance

---

Adding more details to the problem

My config.xml has this

```
  <platform name="windows">
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  </platform>
```

My index.html has this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ms-appdata: 'unsafe-eval';  http: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data: http: blob:; connect-src *; frame-src *;">
```

Using Visual Studio Community 2017 - Windows 10 PC

Running the app using Debug - WIndows x86 - Local Machine.

When the app launches in local machine - works by and large . I mean some feature works and some does not (For example I have sketch Using literally Canvas which is react based Library which does not work).

When I am in  App If i press F12 for debug console - goto Emulation Tab and select Windows 10 Mobile as browser Mode (As in screenshot) Everything start to work - yes Sketch starts to work.

My query is What is it with Browser Mode to Windows 10 Mobile.

So the app works well in "Windwos 10 Mobile" mode and not in "Desktop" mode.

[image]

Comment: can you please explain more about your problem.
but i think as per your question check your config file right click on config file and select View Code and check "windows-target-version" and set it as of your use.

Comment: Yes have tried windows-target-version to 10.0 also have tried this <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />

Comment: your trying to run your code in your windows 10 pc and it's not working correctly right??

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for the reply. Yes  I have the codebase thats works well for Android/IOS. Trying to build the same code for windows 10. Using windows 10 PC. I have made necessary changes such as ms-appdata in meta tag., and Preference in windows platform in config.xml.  Although it works mostly certain features does not work. But if I go to debugger and change the Browser Profile Mode from "Desktop"  to  "Windows 10 Mobile" everything works good.

Comment: I think here is some confusion! Please explain more about your problem that i can help you more easily like upload images to your steps. 
you want to debug your code in your windows pc select Solution Plateform "Windows-AnyCpu" and debug on Local Machine

Comment: I could not run using Windows-AnyCpu - Error says Unsupported platform 0.   Have edited the question with more details and an image. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's because internet explore try to run directly from visual studio. and select Solution Platform as per your desktop and choose debugging Local machine.